# Is it true that the generators of a commutative ring is finite?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

So I am thinking about the structure of a commutative ring $R$. Give a family of principal ideals $A=\{(x_{i})\}$, and if $R=\bigcup_{i}(x_{i})$, is it true that there are finite number of principal ideals in $A$ such that $(1)=(x_{1},x_{2},...,x_{n})$? Actually, this comes from the statement that "Affine schemes are quasi-compact". Can anyone help? Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you mean $\cup_i(x_i)$, and not the ideal generated by the union (equivalently, by elements $x_i$? In both cases the statement is true, but from the given context I presume you mean the latter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $R = \bigcup_i (x_i)$, then $1\in (x_i)$ for some $i$, so one of the principal ideals must be $(1)=R$.